# how to use spring validator to achieve a 'or' logic

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator

I want to validate model with two different conditions
For example,

```
class User{
   private String name;
}
```

I want the **name** can be null or size greater than 5 if it's not null.How can I use the validator.

I know it's ok to create a custom annotation to fit it.However,I have many the same needs in other places too.So I want to use the annotations provided.
In my problem,it will become easy if it provides a way to achieve a **or** logic.

Is there one who can give me a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### custom validator

```
@AssertTrue(message = "name checked")
public boolean isNameCheck() { 
  if (this.name == null || (this.name != null && this.name.length() <= 5)) { 
    return true; 
  }

  return false;
}
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-builtin-constraints